How to enforce wrapping in empty body function in CLion Nova with enabled ReSharper
ReSharper formater changes this code from this:
parse_rule_t::parse_rule_t(token_type t) :
    data(singular_token_rule_t { t }),
    type(parse_rule_type::singular_token) {
}

To this:
parse_rule_t::parse_rule_t(token_type t) :
    data(singular_token_rule_t { t }),
    type(parse_rule_type::singular_token) {}

How can I enforce ReSharper C++ to keep blank line in scopes?
